# what is the proper was to use set_flashdata in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

When I try to set flash data in a method it doesnt exist after a redirect. Here is an example:

```
function logout()
{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('auth_msg', 'you have been logged out');
   redirect('admin/login');
}
```

Problem is when I check for the value of auth_msg in flashdata, it doesnt exist and the user guide doesnt really show what method is bet to use when using this. What is the best method to use with what I am trying to do?

thanks

Comment: when you are using flash data you should be in one one server request if you went pass to another request the flash data will automatically cleared.

Comment: @Venkat, no! That's exactly the purpose of the flash: to persist across requests.

Comment: when i try keep flash it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because flash data uses the session.

You have just destroyed the session on your `logout()` function (I'm guessing).

Therefore this is the *one single place* you cannot use flashdata in your application.

Try it somewhere else and it should work as you have coded.

Comment: or try it here before destroying session